# If condition based look up not working

Tags: perl

I want to look up a range, and return group id, and though a simple if based lookup would work. But, it is not working, I am not sure why.
Can somebody help please.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub get_xid {
        my $x_id = "";

        if(($_[0] ge 1) && ($_[0] le 4))        { $x_id = "x.1"; }
        if(($_[0] ge 5) && ($_[0] le 8))        { $x_id = "x.2"; }
        if(($_[0] ge 9) && ($_[0] le 12))       { $x_id = "x.3"; }
        if(($_[0] ge 13) && ($_[0] le 16))      { $x_id = "x.4"; }
        if(($_[0] ge 17) && ($_[0] le 20))      { $x_id = "x.5"; }
        if(($_[0] ge 21) && ($_[0] le 24))      { $x_id = "x.6"; }
        if(($_[0] ge 25) && ($_[0] le 28))      { $x_id = "x.7"; }
        if(($_[0] ge 29) && ($_[0] le 32))      { $x_id = "x.8"; }

        return $x_id;
}

for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++) {
        $x_id = &get_xid($i);
        print " i: $i, x_id: $x_id\n";
}
```

result:

```
 i: 1, x_id: x.1
 i: 2, x_id: x.5
 i: 3, x_id: x.8
 i: 4, x_id: x.1
 i: 5, x_id: x.2
 i: 6, x_id: x.2
 i: 7, x_id: x.2
 i: 8, x_id: x.2
 i: 9, x_id: 
 i: 10, x_id: x.1
 i: 11, x_id: x.1
 i: 12, x_id: x.1
 i: 13, x_id: x.4
 i: 14, x_id: x.4
 i: 15, x_id: x.4
 i: 16, x_id: x.4
 i: 17, x_id: x.5
 i: 18, x_id: x.5
 i: 19, x_id: x.5
 i: 20, x_id: x.5
 i: 21, x_id: x.6
 i: 22, x_id: x.6
 i: 23, x_id: x.6
 i: 24, x_id: x.6
 i: 25, x_id: x.7
```

Answer (score 3):

In Perl the comparison operators for numbers are `<`, `==`, `>`, `<=`, `>`. If you use the string operators (`le`, `ge`, etc) you are comparing the numbers as strings.  So, for example, `10` is greater than `1` but less than `4`.

Also note that you're doing redundant testing.  Consider

```
    if($_[0] < 1)            { you didn't cover this case }
    elsif($_[0] <= 4)        { $x_id = "x.1"; }
    elsif($_[0] <= 8)        { $x_id = "x.2"; }
    elsif($_[0] <= 12)       { $x_id = "x.3"; }
    etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

`le` and `ge` are for *string comparisons*. Replace them with `<=` and `>=`

Alternatively you can write your function like this

```
sub get_xid {

    my ($v) = @_;

    return $v < 1 || $v > 32 ? "" : 'x.'.int(($v+3)/4);
}
```

#### output

```
 i: 1, x_id: x.1
 i: 2, x_id: x.1
 i: 3, x_id: x.1
 i: 4, x_id: x.1
 i: 5, x_id: x.2
 i: 6, x_id: x.2
 i: 7, x_id: x.2
 i: 8, x_id: x.2
 i: 9, x_id: x.3
 i: 10, x_id: x.3
 i: 11, x_id: x.3
 i: 12, x_id: x.3
 i: 13, x_id: x.4
 i: 14, x_id: x.4
 i: 15, x_id: x.4
 i: 16, x_id: x.4
 i: 17, x_id: x.5
 i: 18, x_id: x.5
 i: 19, x_id: x.5
 i: 20, x_id: x.5
 i: 21, x_id: x.6
 i: 22, x_id: x.6
 i: 23, x_id: x.6
 i: 24, x_id: x.6
 i: 25, x_id: x.7
 i: 26, x_id: x.7
 i: 27, x_id: x.7
 i: 28, x_id: x.7
 i: 29, x_id: x.8
 i: 30, x_id: x.8
 i: 31, x_id: x.8
```